# Why can I return a NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults but not an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving several items in NSUserDefaults in iOS 6. In the past I have always used an NSMutableArray that contains NSMutableDictionaries to save some info. But now I've decided it would be more efficient to use an NSMutableDictionary that contains NSMutableDictionaries. I want to be able to delete dictionaries from the main NSMutableDictionary and modify the values stored in the subdictionaries.

I've been storing my main NSMutableArray as:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)listArray
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] mutableArrayValueForKey:@"list_array"];
}

-(void) setDeviceListArray:(NSMutableArray *)listArray
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:listArray forKey:@"list_array"];
}
```

I would do the same for NSMutableDictionary but there is no getter function like 'mutableDictionaryValueForKey' that exists. Can someone tell me why this is??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just because :D

copy the dictionary like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"bla"].mutableCopy;
```